# Ajax responseText is trimmed for some reason

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

I have a php script which fetch data from server and return array/json. Direct(entering url in browser) accessing this script return desired results (array/json).

But When i access same script with the ajax return array/json is trimmed. For example

This is the output from direct access to script

```
Array
(
    [user_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 46
            [1] => 16
        )

    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Sewak
            [1] => Ram Bachan
        )

    [date] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2016-03-04
            [1] => 2016-03-04
        )

    [zone] => Array
        (
            [0] => North
            [1] => North
        )

    [state] => Array
        (
            [0] => Punjab
            [1] => Punjab
        )

    [city] => Array
        (
            [0] => Patiala
            [1] => Amritsar
        )

    [outlet] => Array
        (
            [0] => asdfasdf
            [1] => Malout Road 1
        )

)
```

Response from Ajax

```
Array
(
    [user_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 16
        )

    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Ram Bachan
        )

    [date] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2016-03-04
        )

    [zone] => Array
        (
            [0] => North
        )

    [state] => Array
        (
            [0] => Punjab
        )

    [city] => Array
        (
            [0] => Amritsar
        )

    [outlet] => Array
        (
            [0] => Malout Road 1
        )

)
```

You can see there are two sets in each array and ajax return only one set(Last one) from the resuts

Here is the php script

```
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
require_once('../../db/conn.php');
//print_r($_REQUEST);
$zone = $_REQUEST['zones'];
$state = $_REQUEST['state'];
$state = "Punjab";
$city = $_REQUEST['city'];
$vmId = $_REQUEST['vm'];
$approval_status = $_REQUEST['approval_status'];
$dealersName = $_REQUEST['outlet'];
$from_date = str_replace("-", "/", $_REQUEST['from_date']);
$to_date = str_replace("-", "/", $_REQUEST['to_date']);

//Creating SQL query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM uploads WHERE 1=1 ";

if (!empty($zone)) {
    $sql .= "AND zone='$zone'";
}
if (!empty($state)) {
    $sql .= "AND state='$state'";
}
if (!empty($city)) {
    $sql .= "AND city='$city'";
}
if (!empty($vmId)) {
    $sql .= "AND user_id='$vmId'";
}
if (!empty($dealersName)) {
    $sql .= "AND outlet_name='$dealersName'";
}
if (!empty($approval_status)) {
    if ($approval_status != "all") {
        $sql .= "AND approved='$approval_status'";
    }
}
if (!empty($from_date)) {
    $sql .= "AND dateTime >= '$from_date'";
}
if (!empty($to_date)) {
    $sql .= "AND dateTime <='$to_date'";
}
//echo $sql;
$searchResults = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Search Failed = >" . mysqli_error($conn));
$id = array();
$name = array();
$date = array();
$zone = array();
$state = array();
$city = array();
$outlet = array();

while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($searchResults)) {
    array_push($id, $data['user_id']);
    array_push($name, $data['name']);
    array_push($date, $data['dateTime']);
    array_push($zone, $data['zone']);
    array_push($state, $data['state']);
    array_push($city, $data['city']);
    array_push($outlet, $data['outlet_name']);
}

$jsonData = array(
    "user_id" => $id,
    "name" => $name,
    "date" => $date,
    "zone" => $zone,
    "state" => $state,
    "city" => $city,
    "outlet" => $outlet
);
print_r($jsonData);
//echo json_encode($jsonData);
exit();
```

Here is the Javascript/Ajax

```
function getResults() {
    loader.style.visibility = "visible";
    var zoneValue = zone;
    var stateValue = state;
    var cityValue = city.value;
    var vmValue = vm.value;
    var outletValue = outlet.value;
    for (var i = 0; i < approved.length; i++) {
        if (approved[i].checked) {
            approvedValue = approved[i].value;
            break;
        }
    }
    var fromValue = from.value;
    var toValue = to.value;
    var params = "query=1&zones=" + zoneValue + "&state=" + stateValue + "&city=" + cityValue + "&vm=" + vmValue + "&approval_status=" + approvedValue + "&outlet=" + outletValue + "&from_date=" + fromValue + "&to_date=" + toValue;
    console.log(zoneValue, stateValue, cityValue, vmValue, outletValue, approvedValue, fromValue, toValue);

    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("POST", "includes/masterData.php", true);
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
            console.log(ajax.responseText);
            loader.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    };
    ajax.send(params);
}
```

Comment: you are not outputing JSON, you have commented out `json_encode` call in your php script.

Comment: @PatrickEvans i have commented out to test script. Output are different of same script when direct access to script and call through ajax. I am outputting array in console.

Comment: Are you passing the same url parameters when browsing directly?

Comment: yes all parameters are same

Comment: Try putting `print_r($_REQUEST)` in the script and see if it's really getting the same parameters.

Comment: Or use `echo $sql` to see if the queries are the same.

Comment: Shouldn't `var zoneValue = zone;` be `var zoneValue = zone.value`, and the same for `stateValue`?

Comment: I am not sure but looks like you might be missing a space at each step before `AND` condition in the way you are conditionally constructing the `$sql` query.

Comment: I think `$sql .= "AND zone='$zone'";` should be `$sql .= " AND zone='$zone'";` and so on.